# Java: How to get a bi-directional numeric representation of a string?

Tags: java

I need to compute a numeric representation of a string which is bi-direction. For example, If I have a string "US" I would like an algorithm which when applied to "US" generates a number X (int or long). When another algorithm is applied to X, I want to get "US". Each string consists of two characters.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll need something much bigger than a `long`.  How large are the strings?

Comment: I'm not sure *bi-directional* is the right word here. Maybe *[bijective](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection)*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following does it easily by using DataInputStream and DataOutputStream to read/write to an underlying byte array.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String original = "US";
    int i = stringToInt(original);
    String copy = intToString(i);

    System.out.println("original: "+original);
    System.out.println("i: "+i);
    System.out.println("copy: "+copy);

}

static int stringToInt(String s) {

    byte[] bytes = s.getBytes();

    if (bytes.length > 4) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("String too large to be" +
                    " stored in an int");
    }

    byte[] fourBytes = new byte[4];
    System.arraycopy(bytes, 0, fourBytes, 0, bytes.length);

    try {
        return new DataInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(fourBytes))
                    .readInt();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("impossible");
    }
}

static String intToString(int i) {

    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        new DataOutputStream(byteArrayOutputStream).writeInt(i);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("impossible");
    }

    return new String(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing is bidirectional encryption. Something like [this](http://www.jasypt.org/) may help you. Another way to do this if you specifically want a numerical value, is to store the character codes (ASCII codes) of each letter. However the resulting number is going to be huge (especially for really long strings) and you probably won't be able to store it in an 32 or 64-bit integer. Even a `long` won't help you here.

**UPDATE**

According to your edit, which says that you only need two characters, you can use the ASCII codes by using `getBytes()` on the String. When you need to convert it back, the first two digits will correspond to the first character, whereas the last two will correspond to the second character.

Comment: The OP said the input strings are only two characters.

Comment: @Jim Didn't see that. I thought it wasn't there in the original question. I think it was an edit.

Answer (score 0):

This is in the general sense impossible; there are only 2^64 long values, and there are more than 2^64 64-character strings consisting only of the characters X, Y and Q.

Maybe you want to have a pair of hash tables A and B and a counter; if you're given a string you check whether it's in the first hash table, if so return the value you stored there, if not then you set

```
A[string]=counter; B[counter]=string; counter=1+counter;
```

Comment: The OP said the input strings are only two characters.

Answer (score 0):

This could do, assuming your Strings have length `2`, i.e. consist of two Java `char` values:

```
public int toNumber(String s) {
    return s.charAt(0) + s.charAt(1) << 16;
}
public String toString(int number) {
    return (char)number + "" + (char)(number >> 16);
}
```

There are Unicode characters (those with numbers over 2<sup>16</sup>) that do not fit into a single Java `char`, but are represented (by UTF-16) by two consecutive surrogates. This algorithm would work for a single-Character-string consisting of these two surrogates, but not for longer strings consisting of more than one such character.

Also, there are `int` values which do not map back to valid Unicode (or UTF-16) strings (e.g. which produce unpaired surrogates instead of valid characters). But each *normal* string gets converted to an int and back to the same string.